# Getting a number of quarter from numeric week number and the week number within the quarter in python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I've a list of number from 1 to 53. I am trying to calculate 1) **the quarter** of a week and 2) **the number of that week within that quarter** using **numeric** week numbers. (if 53, needs to be qtr 4 wk 14, if 27 needs to be 3rd quarter wk 1). Got this working in excel, but not in python? Any thoughts?

tried the following, but at each try I've an issue with the wk's like 13 or 27 depending on the method I'm using.

13 -> should be qtr 1 , 27 -> should be 3 qtr.

```
df['qtr1'] = df['wk']//13
df['qtr2']=(np.maximum((df['wk']-1),1)/13)+1
df['qtr3']=((df1['wk']-1)//13)
df['qtr4'] = df['qtr2'].astype(int)
```

Results are awkward

```
wk      qtr  qtr2   qtr3        qtr4
1.0     0        1.076923  -1.0      1           
13.0    1(wrong)        1.923077   0.0      1           
14.0    1        2.000000   1.0      2           
27.0    2        3.000000   1.0      2 (wrong)          
28.0    2        3.076923   2.0      3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your weeks to integers, by using `astype`:

```
df['wk'] = df['wk'].astype(int)
```

You should subtract it with one first, like:

```
df['qtr'] = ((df['wk']-1) // 13) + 1
df['weekinqtr'] = (df['wk']-1) % 13 + 1
```

since `13//13` will be `1`, not zero. This gives us:

```
>>> df
   wk  qtr  weekinqtr
0   1    1          1
1  13    1         13
2  14    2          1
3  26    2         13
4  27    3          1
5  28    3          2
```

If you want extra columns per quarter, you can use [**`get_dummies(..)`** [pandas-doc]](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) to obtain a one-hot encoding per quarter:

```
>>> df.join(pd.get_dummies(df['qtr'], prefix='qtr'))
   wk  qtr  weekinqtr  qtr_1  qtr_2  qtr_3
0   1    1          1      1      0      0
1  13    1         13      1      0      0
2  14    2          1      0      1      0
3  26    2         13      0      1      0
4  27    3          1      0      0      1
5  28    3          2      0      0      1
```

Comment: Thanks. I had already tried this in qtr3 version, the problem with it is it makes wk1 as -1, also when 27, it produces 1. That should be 2 so that I can simply +1 it to be a quarter 3. Not really sure what's happening to lead this type of division.  My wks are floats, could that be?

Comment: @AtaSagun: you can indeed add `+1`. At first sight it looks like you used floating points for your weeks, you can use `df['wk'].astype(int)` to convert these to ints.

Comment: thanks very much.  the astype(int) did the trick and looked like it was the float causing this - really unintuitve. Regarding the 53rd wk, I extended this by {df.loc[df1['wk']==53,'qtr']=4
df.loc[df1['wk']==53,'weekinqtr']=14}

Answer (score 1):

Using div `//` and modulo `%` work for what you want I think

```
In [254]: df = pd.DataFrame({'week':range(52)})
In [255]: df['qtr'] = (df['week'] // 13) + 1

In [256]: df['qtr_week'] = df['week'] % 13

In [257]: df.loc[(df['qtr_week'] ==0),'qtr_week']=13

In [258]: df
Out[258]:
    week  qtr  qtr_week
0      1    1         1
1      2    1         2
2      3    1         3
3      4    1         4
4      5    1         5
5      6    1         6
6      7    1         7
7      8    1         8
8      9    1         9
9     10    1        10
10    11    1        11
11    12    1        12
12    13    2        13
13    14    2         1
14    15    2         2
15    16    2         3
16    17    2         4
17    18    2         5
18    19    2         6
19    20    2         7
20    21    2         8
21    22    2         9
22    23    2        10
23    24    2        11
24    25    2        12
25    26    3        13
26    27    3         1
27    28    3         2
28    29    3         3
29    30    3         4
30    31    3         5
31    32    3         6
32    33    3         7
33    34    3         8
34    35    3         9
35    36    3        10
36    37    3        11
37    38    3        12
38    39    4        13
39    40    4         1
40    41    4         2
41    42    4         3
42    43    4         4
43    44    4         5
44    45    4         6
45    46    4         7
46    47    4         8
47    48    4         9
48    49    4        10
49    50    4        11
50    51    4        12
```

Comment: Thank you. This is also a solution with the exception that my values occurred to be floats, having astype(int) were required to implement the solution.